# Receive delegate data inside of another function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, delegates

I am working on a simple game similar to air hockey in SpriteKit using Swift. I have an issue where I have created separate player files which delegate the force/direction vector to the main game scene to be used when their is collision between a player and the ball/puck.

This is how I am retrieving the direction vector/force in gameScene class (the main file):

```
    func northForce(_ force: CGVector, fromNorthPlayer northPlayer: NorthPlayer)
    {  
        northPlayerForceForCollision = force
        print("frame in topForce:", frameCounter)
    }
```

I really want to be able to directly access 'force' from the delegate in my collision detection function so that I do not have to spend a frame saving it as a global variable. Is there anyway I can access force without having it in its own function?

This is how I am sending force from my northPlayer class:

```
//pass the vector to the scene (so it can apply an impulse to the puck)
delegate?.northForce(directionVector, fromNorthPlayer: self)
```

More context of northPlayer class:

```
class NorthPlayer: SKShapeNode
{
    //delegate will refer to class which will act on player force
    weak var delegate:NorthPlayerDelegate?

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        northTouchIsActive = true
        var releventTouch:UITouch!
        //convert set to known type
        let touchSet = touches
        
        //get array of touches so we can loop through them
        let orderedTouches = Array(touchSet)


        for touch in orderedTouches
        {
            //if we've not yet found a relevent touch
            if releventTouch == nil
            {
                //look for a touch that is in the activeArea (Avoid touches by opponent)
                if activeArea.contains(CGPoint(x: touch.location(in: parent!).x, y: touch.location(in: parent!).y - frame.height * 0.42))
                {
                    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    releventTouch = touch
                }
                else
                {
                    releventTouch = nil
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (releventTouch != nil)
        {
            //get touch position and relocate player
//            let location = releventTouch!.location(in: parent!)
            let location = CGPoint(x: releventTouch!.location(in: parent!).x, y: releventTouch!.location(in: parent!).y - frame.height * 0.42)
            position = location
        
            //find old location and use pythagoras to determine length between both points
//            let oldLocation = releventTouch!.previousLocation(in: parent!)
            let oldLocation = CGPoint(x: releventTouch!.previousLocation(in: parent!).x, y: releventTouch!.previousLocation(in: parent!).y - frame.height * 0.42)
            let xOffset = location.x - oldLocation.x
            let yOffset = location.y - oldLocation.y
            let vectorLength = sqrt(xOffset * xOffset + yOffset * yOffset)
            
            //get eleapsed and use to calculate speed
            if  lastTouchTimeStamp != nil
            {
                let seconds = releventTouch.timestamp - lastTouchTimeStamp!
                let velocity = 0.015 * Double(vectorLength) / seconds
                
                //to calculate the vector, the velcity needs to be converted to a CGFloat
                let velocityCGFloat = CGFloat(velocity)
                
                //calculate the impulse
                let directionVector = CGVector(dx: velocityCGFloat * xOffset / vectorLength, dy: velocityCGFloat * yOffset / vectorLength)
                
                //pass the vector to the scene (so it can apply an impulse to the puck)
                delegate?.northForce(directionVector, fromNorthPlayer: self)
                delegate?.northTouchIsActive(northTouchIsActive, fromNorthPlayer: self)
            }
            //update latest touch time for next calculation
            lastTouchTimeStamp = releventTouch.timestamp
        }
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is simply access the delegate within the contact/collision detection function so that there is no middleman function which takes an extra frame to store the delegated force into a variable in the main game scene. I think this will make the game smoother and more accurate when playing at high speeds where an extra frame lagging behind can make a big difference.

Comment: Where does 'delegate' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato I added some more detail about my implementation! :)

Comment: I can't tell what is wrong because you don't show all relevant lines of code.

Comment: @ElTomato Nothing per say is wrong with the code, I am just wondering if I can retrieve the force variable from northPlayer directly in another gameScene function. I want to access force inside the contact function instead of with the northForce function. Otherwise I believe the force is an extra frame off when it is applied in collision detection function.